# What is a tee equivalent for network packets?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, tee

This is probably a very basic question.

Wanted to know in Linux if there is a command that could work like the tee command but for forwarding TCP/UDP packets. Basically it should listen at one port and ‘tee’/ forward the same data/packets to all the other hosts configured behind this ‘tee’ like component.

If not a command what would be a recommended setup for the same?

Would netcat or socat be able to do this?

Comment: You found netcat and socat, what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 8):

Network communication is usually bidirectional while `tee` and shell pipelines  only work in a uni-directional way.

But, if you have some network services that only receive and never send back data, you can send the same stream of bytes to all of them over TCP with `zsh` + `socat` with something like:

```
generate-stream > >(socat -u - tcp:host:8001) > >(socat -u - tcp:host:8002)
```

Or with other shells with support for process substitution, but no multios support:

```
generate-stream | tee >(socat -u - tcp:host:8001) | socat -u - tcp:host:8002
```

Now to hook that into a service that takes incoming connections and forward the received traffic in that `tee`ed way, you could do something like:

```
CODE='
  cat > >(socat -u - tcp:host:8001) > >(socat -u - tcp:host:8002)
' socat -u tcp-listen:8000,fork,reuseaddr \
           exec:'zsh -c eval\\ $CODE',nofork
```

Here starting a service that receives traffic over TCP port 8000 (in a unidirectional way) and forwarding it to servers at TCP port 8001 and 8002 on `host`.

The `nofork` is not necessary, it's just an optimisation to have `zsh`'s stdin directly *be* the network socket.

Or if you don't have `zsh` but have `bash`:

```
CODE='
  tee >(socat -u - tcp:host:8001) | socat -u - tcp:host:8002
' socat -u tcp-listen:8000,fork,reuseaddr \
           exec:'bash -c eval\\ \\\"$CODE\\\"',nofork
```

That can be adapted to any of the many other transport protocols supported by `socat`.

You could write a `zsh` helper function for that like:

```
ntee() (
  src=$1; shift
  export CODE=cat
  for dst do
    CODE+=" > >(socat -u - ${(qq)dst})"
  done
  socat -u "$src" exec:'zsh -c eval\\ $CODE',nofork
)
```

And use it as:

```
ntee tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork \
       tcp:host1:8001 \
       udp-sendto:host2:8002 \
       file:file.log,creat,append
```

for instance.

Answer (score 3):

The netcat or socat tools are great for dealing with application layer streams of data.  To forward copies of network packets to other destinations on a Linux machine you want to look at kernel-level `iptables`.

The tee functionality you're looking for could be implemented using the TEE extension: [iptables TEE extension documentation](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDU)

The specific `iptables` rules you'd want to configure will depend on your network interfaces, the number of ports to forward, etc.